# How to check my action is being executed in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

In zend framework, what is the best way to be sure that my controller action is being executed and how can i check different values of the variables in the actions. (Without using debugger)

Comment: You can execute an url that contains the route to the action to see the result of the action.

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump()` ([see manual page](http://php.net/var_dump))

or

`Zend_Log` to any number of destinations. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html

or

`Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug()` for FireBug/FirePHP logging is my favourite. See: http://www.christophdorn.com/Blog/2008/09/02/firephp-and-zend-framework-16/

Comment: I'll check the Zend_log_Writer_Firebug(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put `die(Zend_Debug::dump($anyVariable));` on the line you want to make sure is executed :)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answers (using die() & var_dump/Zend_debug), I'll advise you [ZFDebug toolbar](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/)

[image]

It can show you some relevant informations about the current request.